# Recurse nested object looking for property and add it to array if present

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to traverse an `object` looking for a property or key always with the same name, `subProperty`, in a nested structure. The object can have it once, or several times in different levels without.

This is my current pseudo code.

1. Check if `obj` has the property `subProperty`.
2. If it does not have it, return `false`
3. If it has it, go one level deep (obj.subProperty) and check if it has the property `subProperty` and so on...

I want to do it `recursively` however I cannot make my mind around it. Can anyone help me with the recursion function to check in each level if it has that property and if so, push true to an array

```
const obj = {
  level1: 'level 1',
  subProperty: {
    level2: 'level 2',
    subProperty: {
      level3: 'level 3'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to learn and understand `recursion` 
Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So this function always returns `false`, but may take an arbitrarily long time to do so?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You could return an array with `false` for the level without `subProperty`, otherwise return `true` and the result of the recursive call of the function.

```js
function getLevels({ subProperty }) {
    if (subProperty === undefined) return [false];
    return [true, ...getLevels(subProperty)];
}

const
    object = { level1: 'level 1', subProperty: { level2: 'level 2', subProperty: { level3: 'level 3' } } },
    levels = getLevels(object);

console.log(levels);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question as asked will not really help you learn much about recursion.  Pretty well by definition, the function will always return `false` (unless you have a cyclic object which might recur continually until the stack runs out.)

So here's a variant that I think should help:  Instead of returning `false`, we could return the first nested object without the property `subProperty`.  So for your sample object, this should return a reference to the nested `{level3: 'level 3'}` object.

Since our data structure is obviously recursive, this is a good place to use a recursive solution.  Here's one possibility:

```js
const levelWithoutSubProperty = function (obj) {
  if ('subProperty' in obj) {
    return levelWithoutSubProperty (obj .subProperty)
  }
  return obj;
}

const obj = {level1: 'level 1', subProperty: {level2: 'level 2', subProperty: {level3: 'level 3'}}}

console .log (
  levelWithoutSubProperty (obj)  //~> {level3: 'level 3'}
)
```

Here's how it works:

```js
levelWithoutSubProperty({level1: 'level 1', subProperty: {level2: 'level 2', subProperty: {level3: 'level 3'}}})
// `'subProperty' in obj` returns true, so call `levelWithoutSubProperty` with its subProperty:
    levelWithoutSubProperty({level2: 'level 2', subProperty: {level3: 'level 3'}})
    // `'subProperty' in obj` returns true, so call `levelWithoutSubProperty` with its subProperty:
        levelWithoutSubProperty({level3: 'level 3'})
        // `'subProperty' in obj` returns false so
        return {level3: 'level 3'}
    return {level3: 'level 3'}
return {level3: 'level 3'}
```

Direct recursion (there are other types but they're not much more complex) involves a function calling itself with data that is in some way simplified from its own parameters.  At some point the input must simple enough that you can calculate the result without another recursive call.  This is called a *base case*, and it's important that every recursive function have at least one.  Otherwise the function will continue to call itself indefinitely.

Here our sole base case is when `obj` does not have the property `subProperty`, that is, when `'subproperty' in obj` returns false.  In that case, we simply return the parameter supplied.

A recursive function will also have one or more recursive calls.  Here we only have just one.  We call our function again with the property `subProperty` of our object: `return levelWithoutSubProperty (obj .subProperty)`

---

There are other things we might want to do to this function to make it more robust.  We should probably test that `obj` is actually an object before using `'subProperty' in obj`.  And I prefer to use expressions rather than statements like `if`.  So I would probably write it like this myself:

```js
const levelWithoutSubProperty = (obj) =>
  typeof obj == 'object' && 'subProperty' in obj
    ? levelWithoutSubProperty (obj .subProperty)
    : obj
```

We might want to make the property name to test dynamic, by adding it as a parameter:

```js
const deepest = (propName, obj) => 
  typeof obj == 'object' && propName in obj
    ? deepest (propName, obj [propName])
    : obj
```

and calling it like `deepest ('subProperty', obj)`.

But that changes nothing about the basics.  We have one or more base cases that return a value directly and one or more recursive calls that call our function again with some simplified data.

That's what recursion is all about.

Answer (score -1):

`hasOwnProperty` can check if an object has the property that is specified as an argument. You can create a while loop to continue until a property is found that doesn't have the subproperty. Here is a short script demonstrating a function to do this. It will return the array, with true for all the times that it could continue and false for the last time.

```js
const obj = {
  level1: 'level 1',
  subProperty: {
    level2: 'level 2',
    subProperty: {
      level3: 'level 3'
    }
  }
}

function getSubPropertyRecursive(obj, subProperty) {
  propertyArray = [];
  currentObj = obj
  while (currentObj.hasOwnProperty(subProperty)){
    currentObj = currentObj[subProperty];
    propertyArray.push(true);
  }
  propertyArray.push(false);
  return propertyArray;
}
   
console.log(getSubPropertyRecursive(obj, "subProperty"));
```